# Parameterize ddply in R

Tags: r, plyr

For the data frame:

```
exampleDF <- structure(list(val1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("MX", 
"SS", "VF"), class = "factor"), var2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4)), .Names = c("val1", 
"var2"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

instead of doing:

```
ddply(exampleDF, .(val1), summarize, sum(as.numeric(var2)))
```

Is it possible to parameterize the `ddply` call (something as follows, though I tried it and didn't work):

```
colname <- 'var2'
ddply(exampleDF, .(val1), summarize, sum(as.numeric(colname)))
```

which results in ..

```
  val1 ..1
1   MX  NA
2   SS  NA
3   VF  NA
Warning messages:
1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

We have to call `ddply` for a set of columns in the data frame and generate plots for each result of `ddply`. Hence we wanted to parameterize the `ddply` call instead of repeating the same line for n number of columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a challenge with `summarize`, not `ddply`. You could try and do something with `parse` and `eval`, but in general this is not a good idea. I would do something like:

```
colname <- 'var2'
ddply(exampleDF, .(val1), function(sub_dat) sum(as.numeric(sub_dat[[colname]])))
```

You say you want to create multiple plots like this, however, I've almost always been able to create such a set of plots using facetting in `ggplot2` (created by the same author as `plyr`). See e.g. the documentation of [`facet_wrap`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_wrap.html) and [`facet_grid`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_grid.html).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will look into `facet_wrap`. For the code you suggested, it looks like I cannot perform any other function once I have incorporated your change. i.e. I cannot do: `ddply(exampleDF, colname, function(sub_dat) sum(as.numeric(sub_dat[['var2']])), function(sub_dat) print(length(sub_dat)))` which is what I would also want to do. Error: `Error in .fun(piece, ...) : unused argument(s) (function (sub_dat) print(length(sub_dat)))`